# No such module 'GoogleSignIn' Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.3

I am trying to login with Firebase Google Login. After installing the pods when i import header file
**'GoogleSignIn'** it gives me an error.

**No such module 'GoogleSignIn'**

[image]

Here is my pod file

[image]

I also tried different troubleshoot methods like

1. update pods
2. Restarted Xcode

But none of methods did work for me. How i fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can fix that by cleaning the build with cmd+shift+k and removing the derived data(xcode->preferences->location->derived_data_folder and remove the derived data folder).
If the above process didn't work then reinstall the pods.

- pod deintegrate
- pod cache clean --all
- pod install

Comment: thank you so much for your time. I tried above steps but it didn't work for me. Still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think @muhammad-qais answer will work. If not try removing the text "pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 3.0' " in podfile.
Then pod install. It removes the existing google Sign in pod.
And then install google sign in Pod from cocoapods.org as usual.
Hope it works.